# How to dynamically change 'fromEmailAddress' of cognito forgot password flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am able to change the content of email message using the custom message trigger but couldn't figure out a way to change the `fromEmailAddress` dynamically. I can only set it in `AWS console > Cognito > User Pool > General Setting > Message Customization.`

Is it possible to change the `fromEmailAddress` dynamically using either trigger or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API that allows you to dynamically change the `From E-Mail` address in Amazon Cognito. If you have any doubt on whether Cognito supports something, you could always have a look at the [cognito-idp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/index.html) documentation.